# asm shellcode in C buffer - prologue

Tags: c, assembly, shellcode

I try to build a function in a buffer in C.
with gdb i can translate

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
(...)
leave
ret
```

to

```
0x55
0x48 0x89 0xe5
(...)
0xc9
0xc3
```

So I wrote a C code:

```
int main()
{
   char buffer[]={0x55,0x48,0x89,0xe5,0xc9,0xc3};
   void (*j)(void)=buffer;
   j();
}
```

but my program seems to crash at the intruction "push   rbp" (0x55 in the buffer)
Do you know why?

Comment: You need to provide a **lot** more information.  What is the architecture and operating system?  Is data space executable?  Do you need to do anything special to insure cache consistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual cause is that the stack (where your `buffer` is stored) is not executable. There are primarily two ways around that:

1. compile/link such that the stack is marked executable (ie. `gcc -z execstack`)
2. use `mprotect` at runtime to mark the page where your code is executable